# Incompatible pointer type when I want to refer to a struct variable

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to iterate through a variables of a struct, with a function. When I give the starting address of the pointer, I get a warning: "initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]". When I add this pointer to the function, I got an other warning: "passing argument 1 of ‘ManipulateMessage’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]". I've searched these errors, but the results didn't help me. The code actually is working, but I want to avoid undefined behavior. What is the cleanest way of this simple code?

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

/*************************************************
include
**************************************************/
//A message structure
typedef struct SIGNAL_STRUCTURE
{
    int name;
    int manipstarttime;
} signal_structure;

//Structure what collects all the signals 
typedef struct SIGNAL_COLLECTOR
{
    signal_structure EngSpeed;
    signal_structure TransReqGear;
    signal_structure CurrentGear;
} signal_collector;

//Function to do with the above structure
void ManipulateMessage(signal_structure * signal)
{
    signal->name = 10;
    signal->manipstarttime = 11;
}

/*************************************************
main
**************************************************/
void fcn(signal_collector * param_signal, int len)
{
    int *pointer = param_signal;
    
    while(len--)
    {
        printf("pointer: %p\n", pointer);
        ManipulateMessage(pointer);
        pointer += (sizeof(signal_structure) / sizeof(int));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    signal_collector dummy;
    fcn(&dummy, 2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you even trying to treat a `signal_structure *` as an `int *`?

Comment: Replace `int *pointer` with `signal_structure *pointer` and `pointer += (sizeof(signal_structure) / sizeof(int));` with `pointer++;`

Comment: `fcn()` expects the argument to be an array of `signal_collector` structures. You're passing a single `signal_collector`, but telling it that there are 2 of them in the `len` argument.

Comment: Also, `while (len--)` will iterate 3 times, not 2 times. `while (--len)` will iterate 2 times.

Comment: Why are you using pointer arithmetic? `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { do something with param_signal[i] }`

Comment: @Kevin Or skip the use of `pointer` to begin with, and use `param_signal` directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Like `for (int i=0;i<len;i++,param_signal++) ManipulateMessage(param_signal);`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Something like that. But I would probably use `size_t i` instead... :)

Comment: @Barmar I thought it is only feasable with pointer. But what is the solution if I want to choose the pointer method? - just for practicing. Because since the function *ManipulateMessage* argument is `signal_structure * `, and I pass the pointer, what is now `signal_collector * `. Therefore I have another incompatible pointer time.

Comment: Pointers can be used like arrays. `*(pointer + n)` is equivalent to `pointer[n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `fcn()` you get `signal_collector * param_signal`, but on the second line you say     `int *pointer = param_signal;`. So you cast `signal_collector` to `int`, and then you send `pointer` which is of type `int *` to `ManipulateMessage()`, which expect `signal_structure *` as an argument.

Do you see the problem? In order to resolve this issue, change the second line in `fcn()` to:

```c
signal_collector *pointer = param_signal;
```

Comment: Also, needs to change the pointer increments.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I thought that the pointer containing only the address of a memory segment, so it ought to be a number variable, like an integer. Look like I need more homework to do with the pointers.